# Did Transcrypt support HTML 5?

Tags: transcrypt

Did this tool Transcrypt http://www.transcrypt.org/ support HTML 5?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use it in combination with HTML5.
Several demos use the HTML5 canvas.
In fact you can use it for anything you can use JavaScript for.

Answer (score 0):

Transcrypt only does the 'scripting'. It will support HTML5 as long as you spit 'HTML5' to the DOM/Browser.

So, the short answer is 'Yes, Transcrypt supports HTML5'.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of using python for html5 programming in

https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/

Even game engines can be programmed easily with it. e.g. 
https://github.com/bunkahle/Transcrypt-Examples/blob/master/games/solar_system05.py